# Create modal page dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have a conceptual question, when i want create a modal in my page, always include the `html` of my modal in the page, something like this :

```
<div class="my-modal">
 <form action="/home/index">
  <input type="text" class="txt-name"/>
  <input type="text" class="txt-last-name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="register!"/>
 </form>
</div>
```

Usually i show this modal by `jquery` plugins, like `blockUI` and etc.
Now i have some questions in my mind and i want to do the best:

- Always i should include this section in my `html` page, but maybe the
  user doesn't need to using this, maybe he need another sections but i
  use the memory.
- When using this modal form, always i need to reset or re-initial my
  modal form and it's so boring to doing this stuff when i have
  multiple modals in the page.

So i need a technique, plugin or etc. to handle these issues.
Any idea for this?

**UPDATE**

After some searches i think should use some libraries like `requirejs`, but i don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS would load the template ondemand, but not the markup!

Take an eyes to this:

Angular > ng-if > custom directives (transclude: true)

Comment: You mean i should load the template with RequireJs then using Angular to markup?

Comment: No, requireJS is handling the conditionnal script loading, but his goal is not to handle templating. To be able to manage this with some skill, take a look to angular, how provide all stuff you need.